# Touchpad problem in 17.10

Tags: touchpad, 17.10

I just updated to 17.10, at first my touchpad works fine, after a few minutes it freezes and start to clicking repeatedly, if i plug an external mouse it works but with a lag, if works fine if i plug it before the touchpad frezees

this is the info of the driver

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=06cb Product=2970 Version=0111 
N: Name="   Touchpad" 
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input0 
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb4/41/41:1.0/0003:06CB:2970.0002/input/input10
U: Uniq= 
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9  
B: PROP=5 
B: EV=b 
B: KEY=6420 10000 0 0 0 0 
B: ABS=260800000000003
```